# ASP.NET MVC 4: keeping Index as defaul view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

By default MVC 4 application has the following routes in `ProjectFolder\App_Start\RoutConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }   
);
```

In browser, any call to `http://host:port/controller/` would take you to `http://host:port/controller/Index`.

Now, if you want to change the start page, lets say `SomeController\MyAction`, you can change it like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "MyAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }   
);
```

But then `http://host:port/controller/` won't display `http://host:port/controller/Index` but the 404 error page. You would need to explicitly append `/Index` in URL.

If you change the startup page from project properties and keep the routes to Home\Index, then everything would work fine except the URL root `http://host:port/` won't display the startup page. When you run the application it will append the startup page name in the URL. But if you have relative hyperlink like `<a href="/" title="home">Home</a>` somewhere in your application, it would not take you to the desired homepage

Is there a way to configure the startup page "SomeController\MyAction" such that; root URL always point to it and the `Index` be the default view of every controller?

Something equivalent to Ruby on Rails' route:

```
root :to => "some_controller#my_action"
```

which keeps the default view binding to `index` action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add extra route just for Site root, before default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(name: "SiteRoot", url: "",
                    defaults: new { controller = "SiteRoot", action = "Main" });

    routes.MapRoute(name:"Default", url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults:new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

Now `"/"` will take you to `SiteRoot/Main`, while `"/Home"` will take you to `Home/Index`.

Note that in this case `"/SiteRoot"` will also take you to `"SiteRoot/Index"`, not to `"SiteRoot/Main"`. This can be easily changed with additional route specific for `url: "/SiteRoot"`.

Additionally, if you want to be extra precise, in default route you can remove part `controller = "Home"`, since 1st route now covers this case. However, leaving default route as it is will also work.

```
routes.MapRoute(name:"Default", url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults:new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SomeController Default",
    url: "SomeController/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }   
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }   
);
```

This is the how the default routing for `ASP.NET Web API` works, like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: It didn't worked as expected. Please read the question again.